# Spring MVC Webapp - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-security

My `webapp` worked well until I try to use `spring-security`.
Since I add `Spring-security-config`, `Spring-security-core` and `Spring-security-web` in version `3.2.3.RELEASE` I have this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
6 oct. 2014 17:58:46 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
```

With this change I had to pass all my `Spring dependencies` in version `3.2.3.RELEASE`
Before this my Spring libraries where in version `3.0.1`

My `Webapp` is not a maven one. I put all the libraries I need in `WEB-INF/lib`

The other Spring libraries that I have are:

```
Spring-aop 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-asm 3.0.1.RELEASE
Spring-beans 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-context 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-core 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-expression 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-jdbc 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-orm 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-tx 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-web 3.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-webmvc 3.2.3.RELEASE
```

This is the first time I try to secure a Java application. For this I followed this tutorial:
[MKyong - Spring Security Hello World](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/)

Comment: I guess some of the class is missing. Make sure you have all the requires dependencies in your classpath for eg. logging libraries.

Comment: For starters don't mix versions... The spring-asm belongs to Spring 3.0 not 3.2 (where is doesn't exist anymore, remove it). The class that is missing is in the `spring-web` jar, which should be in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Also I strongly suggest the use of something like maven or gradle as it will save you a lot of searching the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I let the Spring-asm in version 3.0.1 because I couldn't find a 3.2.3.RELEASE. So I will delete it.
I am writting my pom to use maven. But before I switch to maven I would like to make my web-app work again...
I can also say that if I try to search the missing class in my workspace I can find it in Spring-web and this one is in my WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I deleted the Spring-asm but I still have the same exception....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M.Deinum said, I tried to create a pom with all my dependencies and it resolved my problem...